# Add a class to first div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to add a class to first div using jQuery.

I Tried following code but doesn't work for me.
maybe I'm missing something.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$('.item')
    .eq(0).addClass('first').end()
    .eq(-1).addClass('last').end();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.first, .last{
background-color:#0099FF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="item">aaa</div>
<div class="item">bbb</div>
<div class="item">ccc</div>
<div class="item">ddd</div>
<div class="item">eee</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Thanks to everyone, is there anyway to add a class to rest of DIVs?

Comment: You are missing DOM ready: `$(function() { ... });`.

Comment: Answer for your edit: `$(".item:not(:first,:last)").addClass("newClass");`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are executing the code before the markup is ready. Wrap the code in

```
// document ready short-style
$(function() {

});
```

Comment: This should come up as a reminder whenever anyone goes to post a jQuery question.

Comment: +1 Really Thanks, It works now. how can I add a class to rest of DIVs?

Answer (score 5):

try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item:first-child').addClass('first');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, but it's executed before the DOM is ready, please move the `<script></script>` to the last line before `</body>`.

To add a class to the rest of the elements you can do this (from VisioN's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798319/add-a-class-to-first-div-using-jquery/12798379#comment17305439_12798319))

```
$(".item:not(:first,:last)").addClass("differentClass");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".item :first").addClass('first');
```

Answer (score 2):

your code should execute when the DOM is fully loaded. So use  $(document).ready().

> the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully
>   constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be
>   executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to
>   attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.

[Read more](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) about $(document).ready().

check the code below. It will help you to get done what you want.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.item').first().addClass('first');
        });
```

Otherwise your js is ran even before the DOM is loaded

`$(".item:first").addClass('first');` will work fine too.

**[Try the demo too.](http://jsfiddle.net/62ZGK/)**

Hope this will help you out. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks

Comment: The correct selector should not contain space: `$(".item:first")`.

Comment: corrected. in the demo it did work with a space. anyway thanks for pointing out :-)

Answer (score 2):

u use this code

```
$(function(){
   $(".item:first-child").addClass("anyclass");
})

or
  $("div:first-child").addClass("anyclass");
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the jQuery code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body .item:first').addClass('YOUR CLASS VALUE');
});
<script>
```

Regards,
http://www.santoshkori.com

Answer (score 1):

see jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BrEcL/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div:first').addClass('first');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

***JS CODE***

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.item')
     .eq(0).addClass('first').end()
     .eq(-1).addClass('last').end();
});
```

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c28S2/5/)***

#### Note

you need to use `$(function() { ... })` to wrap whole jQuery code.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use straight CSS, although it is CSS3. E.g. you could replace your curre t CSS with:

```
.item:nth-of-type(1), .item:nth-of-type(3)
{
   background-color:#0099FF;
}
```

If you do just want jQuery then you could try:

```
$('.item:first').addClass('first');
$('.item:last').addClass('last');
```

Comment: As others have mentioned, the jQuery needs to be in a ready() function else it runs before the page is rendered.